# How can I implement omitType method in XStream?

Tags: converters, xstream

There is an omitField method in XStream to not serialize a specific field.

What I want to do is not to serialize any fields with a specific type.

My current implementation use a custom converter.

In marshal method, it does nothing. That's fine.

However, in unmarshal method, it cannot just return null. Otherwise, when unmarshalling an object that contains a reference to that object would throw an invalid reference exception.

So, I return a proxy object. This can provide another feature I want through the proxy object but I cannot create such a object for some types. I am not asking this problem in this post.

What I want to know is how can I ignore the invalid reference exception to successfully deserialize the object?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can implement omitType method in an easier way using omitField and reflection.

Below is my current implementation.

```
public void omitType(Class<?>... definedIn) {
    for (Class<?> clazz : definedIn) {
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            omitField(clazz, field.getName());
        }
    }
}
```